# How can I display an iframe on button click in c# and also make it invisible when another grid or iframe is displayed?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, iframe

I'm building a database driven web App using asp.net/c# in visual studio 10
(actually it's my first one so I hope the question is not stupid or something)  What code I should write in the Button_Click Event in the behind code to display the iframe when the button is clicked and also being hidden when another object is loaded (for example a Gridview) ? I couldn't find any matching script in any other answer. This is the code for the iframe:

```html
<asp:Panel>
  
  
//...some code about gridviews and dropdownlists....//
  

<div id ="Frame" class="iframe">
  
<iframe name="iframe" id="iframe1" src="AddProject.aspx" class="iframe>
                                                                
</iframe>
                                                                
</div> 
                                                                
</asp:Panel>
                                                                           
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Project" Width="127px"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the runat property in your div to make it work

```
<div id="Frame" runat="server">
```

you could hide the div where the i frame is in

in your button click event you place:
     Frame.Visible = true; // to show the div
and  
     Frame.Visible = false; // to hide the div

This should also work on the iframe itself

this you can also use on a controls like gridview .ect

```
 GridView1.Visible = true;
 GridView1.Visible = false;
```

Comment: thanks! But the problem seems to be that c# does not recognize the (div id) Frame as an object as it does with a Gridview for example so I must find another way to use it in the button click event  :-(